# varargs and null argument

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, variadic-functions

So, I have a weird issue.
This expression: `method.invoke(target, null)` throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

The problem is that this expression is deep inside hibernate (BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter to be precise) and I guess it should work fine (it did until recently)

I debugged this problem in eclipse and indeed, if I (in Display view) call `method.invoke(target)` or `method.invoke(target, (Object[]) null)` everything works fine.
I'm sure my class has this getter and it has no arguments. So ... the question is, what the hell is going on?!

EDIT:

- method is an instance of java.lang.reflect.Method and points to the said getter
- target is an instance of the class with public X getX() getter
- JDK 1.6.0_31
- code in hibernate (BasicPropertyAccessor:143) :

  ```
  public Object get(Object target) throws HibernateException {
      try {
          return method.invoke(target, null);
      }
      catch{ ... }
  }
  ```

Comment: What method are you trying to invoke?

Comment: session.flush() :P But in the end, hibernate is trying to invoke the getter

Comment: what is the signature of the method?

Comment: What version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: M2_REPO\org\hibernate\hibernate\3.2.3.ga\hibernate-3.2.3.ga.jar

Comment: what exactly does it say in the Hibernate code? Does it literally say `method.invoke(target, null)`? or does it say `method.invoke(target, someVariable)`? if the latter, what is the type of `someVariable`?

Comment: I've added snippet from hibernate to the original question

Answer (score 9):

When you pass a `null` value to a varargs method, it could be interpreted as one of two things:

- A `null` array
- An array with one element which is `null`.

Java chooses the former unless the `null` is explicitly cast to the component type of the varargs method. (It is recommended that you explicitly cast either way for clarity, you'll also get an obnoxious warning in Eclipse if you don't.)

When invoking methods with no arguments, you can either pass `Method.invoke` an array with 0 elements, no extra arguments (which will result in an empty array), or a `null` array:

```
public class MethodInvoke {
    public static void noParams() {
        System.out.println("noParams called");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException,
            SecurityException, IllegalAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Method noParams = MethodInvoke.class.getMethod("noParams");
        Object target = null;
        noParams.invoke(target, new Object[0]);
        noParams.invoke(target);
        noParams.invoke(target, null);
        noParams.invoke(target, (Object[]) null);
        noParams.invoke(target, (Object) null); // wrong number of arguments
    }
}
```

What appears to be happening is that `method.invoke(target, null)` is being interpreted as `method.invoke(target, (Object) null)`. That is inconsistent with how Java is supposed to behave.

Are you absolutely sure that your method has no parameters?

I also noticed that in newer version of hibernate they explicitly cast that `null` to `Object[]`.

Comment: well, i cleared maven repository, recreated database, workspace, .project and .classpath files and it started to work. I still have no clue why it behaved so weird.

Comment: @mabn Yeah, this is a really strange bug. At least if it comes back to bite you again you'll know what to do

Answer (score 0):

If the signature of the method is `public X getX()`, then there are *no* parameters, so call it like this:

```
method.invoke(target);
```

The first parameter of the `invoke()` method is the instance upon which to invoke the method.

Note that for varargs methods, the way you specify parameters with commas eg `method(a, b, c)` is syntactic sugar for `method(new Object[]{a, b, c}`: the formal parameter type is `Object[]`.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. See my answer

Comment: I cannot change the expression the the one you provided, hibernate invokes that.